# Is it possible to define "Word boundary" characters for a text box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

*(I cannot believe this has never been asked; most likely I failed at searching.)*

Having a single line WinForms [`TextBox` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) with content in it:

[image]

When the user uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, the caret moves to the very end respectively very beginning of the content of the text box.

#### My goal

I want to configure the text box so that navigating with the above keys (or in addition with <kbd>Shift</kbd>), the caret **stops at word boundaries**.

E.g. when the caret is at position 0 and the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> it would look like this:

[image]

I.e. it selects the first "word" only.

The standard behaviour is:

[image]

I.e. it selects the whole text.

Interestingly enough, the native Windows controls like e.g. in the "Run" dialog behave as described:

[image]

The address bar of Edge or Internet Explorer or even Windows Explorer also stops at word boundaries.

#### My question

Is it possible (maybe through P/Invoke) to configure certain stop characters for the `TextBox` control?

#### Update 1

I could think of handling keyboard events and doing this manually.

Comment: The richtextbox control has the behavior you are looking for :) set multiline to false

Comment: @VisualBean Is it possible to have a single line RTF control?

Comment: Set multiline to false :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question.. definitely, but I wouldn't know how.

But

There is a control that has the behavior you're looking for, namely the `RichTextBox`.
It has the behavior you are asking for and has a property for disabling the default multiline behavior.

## Properties to make the RichTextbox look like a regular textbox

- Multiline - false
- DetectUrls - false
- height - 20

Note:
The richTextBox does **NOT** have autocomplete out of the box, like the regular textbox does.